# How to receive input 21122001 as dmyyyy? I just can enter 21122001 as format ddmmyyyy

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while

```js
if ((input2 == "ddmmyyyy") || (input2 == "dd/mm/yyyy") || (input2 == "dd-mm-yyyy")) {
  (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
  let lMonth = splitinput[2] + splitinput[3];
  let lDay = splitinput[0] + splitinput[1];
  const lYear = input1.slice(4, 8);
  var zero = splitinput[0].replace(/0*\d/g, '');
  var xero = splitinput[2].replace(/0*\d/g, '');

  if ((lMonth <= 12) && (lDay <= 31)) {
    if (input3 == "ddmmyyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (lDay + lMonth + lYear);
    } else if (input3 == "ddyyyymm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "mmyyyydd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "mmddyyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyyddmm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyymmdd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "dd-mm-yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "dd-yyyy-mm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "mm-yyyy-dd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "mm-dd-yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy-dd-mm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy-mm-dd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "dd/mm/yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "dd/yyyy/mm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "mm/yyyy/dd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "mm/dd/yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy/dd/mm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy/mm/dd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    }

    //0 auto disappear for day//
    else if (input3 == "dmmyyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "dyyyymm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "mmyyyyd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "mmdyyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + zero + splitinput[1] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyydmm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + zero + splitinput[1] + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyymmd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "d-mm-yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "d-yyyy-mm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "mm-yyyy-d") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "mm-d-yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "-" + zero + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy-d-mm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + zero + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy-mm-d") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "-" + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "d/mm/yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "d/yyyy/mm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "mm/yyyy/d") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "mm/d/yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "/" + zero + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy/d/mm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + zero + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy/mm/d") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + splitinput[2] + splitinput[3] + "/" + zero + splitinput[1]);
    }

    //0 auto disappear for month//
    else if (input3 == "ddmyyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + xero + splitinput[3] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "ddyyyym") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "myyyydd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "mddyyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyyddm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyymdd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + xero + splitinput[3] + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "dd-m-yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "-" + xero + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "dd-yyyy-m") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "m-yyyy-dd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "m-dd-yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy-dd-m") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "-" + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy-m-dd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + xero + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "dd/m/yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "/" + xero + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "dd/yyyy/m") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "m/yyyy/dd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "m/dd/yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy/dd/m") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1] + "/" + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy/m/dd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + xero + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[0] + splitinput[1]);
    }

    //0 auto disappear for day and month//
    else if (input3 == "dmyyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + xero + splitinput[3] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "dyyyym") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "myyyyd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "mdyyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + zero + splitinput[1] + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyydm") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + zero + splitinput[1] + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyymd") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + xero + splitinput[3] + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "d-m-yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + "-" + xero + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "d-yyyy-m") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "m-yyyy-d") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "m-d-yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + "-" + zero + splitinput[1] + "-" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy-d-m") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + zero + splitinput[1] + "-" + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy-m-d") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "-" + xero + splitinput[3] + "-" + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "d/m/yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + "/" + xero + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "d/yyyy/m") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (zero + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "m/yyyy/d") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else if (input3 == "m/d/yyyy") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (xero + splitinput[3] + "/" + zero + splitinput[1] + "/" + splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy/d/m") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + zero + splitinput[1] + "/" + xero + splitinput[3]);
    } else if (input3 == "yyyy/m/d") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (splitinput[4] + splitinput[5] + splitinput[6] + splitinput[7] + "/" + xero + splitinput[3] + "/" + zero + splitinput[1]);
    } else {
      alert("Please enter the correct output format!");
    }

  } else {
    alert("Please check your month and day!");
  }
}
```

Comment: First: what are you actually trying to do? Second: where is `splitinput` coming from?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please update the snippet we made you to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @empiric obviously `splitinput = "21122001".split("")`

Comment: Who would enter a date in dyyyymm and some of your other esoteric formats? Why not just use a date picker???

Comment: I have updated the coding.@empiric

Comment: the requirement that I am studying is cannot use date picker @mplungjan